# Passing variables in Varnish per request

Tags: varnish

How do I pass variables across subroutines?

I have following default.vcl:

```
vcl 4.0;

sub vcl_recv {
     set req.http.x-tracking-first-request = "true";
}


sub vcl_deliver {

    if (resp.http.x-tracking-first-request) { 
       # do something
    }
}
```

Currently I have to handle the parameter in my backend, i.e. something like `response.add_header("x-tracking-first-request", response.get_header("x-tracking-first-request"))`. This implies that *every* client has to implement this "reflection" logic.

Why? Uppon first request I want to generate a uuid to later identify different users. Therefore I have to somehow save the uuid across all request/response cycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to use the `req` object during `vcl_deliver`:

```
vcl 4.0;

sub vcl_recv {
     set req.http.x-tracking-first-request = "true";
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if (req.http.x-tracking-first-request) { 
       # do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had a typo in on of my header variables and therefore it seemed like I wasn't able to access the req-object.